# how to get custom attachment url?

Tags: wp-query, loop, attachments

Is there a common method to get a custom attachment URL regardless of the plugin or custom code used?

Say if I use ACF plugin 
I can create an image field and get the url with `get_field('fieldname');`

if it is WordPress featured image i use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url();`

for wocoommerce it has, it's on method

if I create a custom meta field for image...is there any loop function to get the URL for the uploaded images?

like `some_function('field', 'size')` which is common to all the above the method?

Comment: if you have attachment id then yes. you can use something like get_the_attachment_url($attach_id). please verfiy the signature before using

Comment: @siddhesh whether it works on loop? how attachment_id and custom image field are linked?

Comment: i used get_post_meta() in combination with get_the_attachment_url..now it works thank you